# xcode: property 'title' 'copy' attribute does not match super class 'UIViewController' property

Tags: iphone, xcode, compilation, warnings

Hi I'm currently getting this error message. and by the love of banana, I cannot figure out what I am not doing right.

Its just an

```
IBOutlet UILabel *title;
```

and

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
```

I've made which is connected to my xib file connected to a UILabel because I dynamically change the title during run time.

Classes/../taskViewController.h:44: warning: property 'title' 'copy' attribute does not match super class 'UIViewController' property

I dont understand what it means.
Normally i am able to get rid of warning messages. But this one... I dont have a clue whats going on.

Can someone please guide me and explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is that UIViewController already defines a title property and you are using a different memory manangement option than it does. To fix this, change the name of your property. ex: `@property (nonatomic, copy) UILabel *titleLabel;`. If you want the instance variable to have the same name, and you use @synthesize, use `@synthesize titleLabel=title;`.

As an aside, why are you copying a UILabel? Normally you would use retain so that it is the same object.

Comment: this is what i have ... I don't have the word 'copy', I do indeed have the word 'retain' in it..... @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

Comment: Then UIViewController must use copy. I would have expected that since it is an NSString, but I thought the error would give what you used.

Comment: changing the label name helped. Thank you very much for this help. So if I understand correctly, UILabel is a subclass of UIViewController which contains a property called title and I named my variable name title which conflicted with that property.. causing that warning to appear

Comment: No, UILabel is a subclass of UIView. The class where you have this property is a subclass of UIViewController. Other than that, yes.

Answer (score 3):

It means:

- you have a subclass of UIViewController
- it contains a property named "title"
- you have declared the property with the "copy" attribute
- the parent class (UIViewController) already has "title" property with a conflicting definition (i.e., not "copy")

Comment: but i havent?  all ive done is.... @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

Comment: Ok, maybe the message is backwards then, and it's `UIViewController` that's declaring it `copy`. In any case, you probably want to change your variable name to avoid the conflict, as ughoavgfhw suggests.

Comment: @DavidGelhar so the subclass 's attribute will override the superclass 's attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i want to just clarify that title is a predefined object in the UIViewController so you cannot create your own objects with that same name, change the with some thing else and see that it wont give you that error.